# observer gets called without changing "playbackLikelyToKeepUp" iOS

Tags: ios, avplayer

I am writing a custom video player and here is my doubt:
Even though the value for the key "playbackLikelyToKeepUp" doesn't change,observer method is getting called.Here is the screenshot below:[image]

How is this possible?
Here is the code:

```
    -(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context{
 if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"]){
        NSLog(@"%@",change[@"new"]);
        if([change valueForKey:@"new"] == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES])
            [myPlayer play];
        NSLog(@"%@",change);
        }
    }
```

and in the viewDidLoad method:

```
        [myPlayerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

and you can see the screenshot above.

Comment: Show the code that sets the observer.  Show the details in text, not image form.  Also that log output does not match the code.

Comment: I have added the code.Can I get the answer now?